# Why does setTimeout in a while loop increment in order?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I had a question at the interview. I just don't get why this prints 5 6 7 8 9...

```
let i = 0;

while (i < 5) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i++);
  }, 0);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: The entire while loop runs before the first timeout fires. That’s the nature of async javascript. Your code runs to completion before async callbacks start.

Comment: When using setTimeout you are adding a reference to i so i gets incremented to 5 before it starts calling the setTimeout()

Comment: You can read more about Event Loop in JS in order to understand this. I recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code starts with `i = 0`.
- When it enters the `while` loop, it'll be incremented to `1, 2, 3, 4` and stop when it reaches `5`.
- The `setTimeout` function is asynchronous, so even with a delay of 0, it'll be called after the current thread finishes (the `while` loop).
- Since `i` was at `5` when the `while` loop ended, the `setTimeout` functions will pick it up from there, outputting its value and incrementing it by one on each subsequent `console.log()`

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the setTimeout () function. Even though it delays 0 seconds. This will lower it's priority in processor. All 5 actions inside setTimeout functions will run after the while loop. Since at the end of it i is 5. So it logs and increments after that...

Comment: `This will lower it's priority in processor.` what?  no it doesn't.  No matter what interval is specified, the enqueued action will not execute until the main execution context has yielded control back to the browser.  If the interval expires before that happens, it will wait, and that is what happens here.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it.